# How to change the anchor on infobubble

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there anyway to change the anchor point of an infobubble?  I would like the point of the infobubble to be at the top center of a 26px x 26px icon.

I'm using Maps API for JavaScript 3.0.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use css:

```
  /*move the bubble 26px upwards*/
.H_ib{margin-top:-26px;}
  /*remove the ellipsis at the end of the tail when you want to*/
.H_ib_tail svg path:first-child{display:none;}
```